# Como implementar um sistema de confirmação de usuário convidado por email

Tags: php

No sistema, o cadastro de usuário não será livre. Cada usuário será convidado por e-mail pelo *administrador* para participar.

Na tabela de usuários tenho, resumidamente, os seguintes atributos:

```
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
$table->string('nome', 45);
$table->string('email', 64)->unique();
$table->string('username', 45)->nullable();
$table->string('senha', 20)->nullable();
$table->string('codigo', 100)->nullable();
$table->boolean('ativo')->default(false);
```

Nunca trabalhei com esse tipo de confirmação, então imaginei o seguinte algoritmo (sequência):

1. Para convidar um usuário, o *administrador* deve preencher o **nome** e **email** do convidado.
2. Sendo assim, o usuário convidado receberá um email com o convite.
3. No e-mail encaminhado, haverá um link que aponta para a rota: hostname/**codigo** (onde **codigo** é um atributo com conteúdo único para cada usuário convidado).
4. Caso essa rota for acessada o usuário se torna **ativo** no sistema.

Esse passo-a-passo para autenticação de usuário seria, relativamente, o mais correto? E a senha? Seria conveniente o *administrador* setar uma senha inicial para o convidado? Preciso de ideias.

Comment: Acho que esses passos estão no caminho certo, fazer uma senha ou deixar o usuario setar a senha fica a seu critério, na verdade não existe um "problema" para ser solucionado nessa pergunta, ficou ampla, veja se consegue reformular, antes que vá para a fila de suspensão.

Answer (score 4):

Você Pode fazer o seguinte, crie um sistema onde fica pedindo email e nome da pessoa, e por traz faz com que crie um token com número randômico e depois criptografa em md5, salve esse valor, o id do usuário, o email do usuário e o nome dessa pessoa. Na função mail(), crie um link com o código gerado, email e id tudo em um link.

Crie uma página para receber esses valor e valide no banco de dados, se  for correto, crie uma session de qualquer nome e coloque um valor e depois direcione para uma pagina, onde o usuário irá concluir o cadastro, com nome completo e bla bla. Essa página só vai entrar se existir a session que vai ser criada se o resultado for positivo. Lembre-se de fazer a pagina deletar o token dele, para outra pessoa não usar.

Se quiser pode criar um outro script para atualizar o token se o usuário entrar no link e não concluir o cadastro e enviar um novo email com o link.